# App Store: transferring an iOS app and app ID

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, app-id

This is the first time I'm about to make a transfer of an app to another company's through iTunes Connect. Is it possible to change the app ID once tranferred and the new company has received it? And the app name for the Store?

Thanks!

Comment: i guess it is possible if we change the bundle identifier of app(which is unique) and the appName.

Comment: @CharanGiri No, you can never change the bundle identifier. Only the app name can be changed.

Comment: you want app name to be same and change of owner? Then there is nothing we can do.

Comment: @CharanGiri yes, the idea is to make the app take a new bundle ID, but keeping its name in the Store, what you say that is not possible... So should we have to remove the app from the Store to make the name available again and make a new submission with a new bundle ID?

Comment: @AppsDev I'm not sure about it(removing app in store and resubmitting with new bundle identifier).one of my application was rejected in store saying it is a book application. So i changed the APP Name and resubmitted with few changes in app and it was approved. Trying doesn't hurt. delete app in store and submit it with new bundle identifier. If it was approved every thing is fine. in the other case change the app name by capitalizing and add some text to it(for sure this will approve). All the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not change the App ID (App id is generated by Apple) or Bundle ID (This identifies the App).

You can change the name with an update.

Comment: When you say "App ID" you mean the SKU number? Is it possible to see the bundle identifier in an iOS device/App Store/iTunes? I mean, is it possible for a user to see the bundle identifier of an app somehow, or this is absolutely not possible and it is something only managed in Xcode/Apple Developers accounts/iTunes Connect?

Comment: The App ID its the number of the app in iTunes, like : https://itunes.apple.com/nl/app/zeilsteen/id367827945?l=en&mt=8 is this case the App ID is `367827945`. And no the user can really see bundle ID, they may be able to retrieve it easily on a jailbroke device or using iExplorer.

Comment: Thanks. Another question comes to me: is it possible to submit an app from different accounts with different bundle IDs, but same name? Is an app name unique for a certain account, or is it unique for the entire App Store?

Comment: how much time it takes to do this process

Comment: @MohammadSadiqShaikh what process?

Answer (score 3):

Once the transfer is completed, you can change the app name by submitting a new version. However you cannot change the app id nor bundle id.

Comment: Thanks. I'm confused about what you name "app id", I think I was really thinking about the bundle id. I suppose the app name should be unique in the App Store, so if you want to change the bundle id of an app but keep the app name, you'll have to remove firstly the former app to release its name... right?

Comment: Change the bundle iD will just make your app a new app, as in existing user will not see it as an update. So the hole transferring of the app was pointless.

Comment: Indeed, app name should be unique, so first you should delete the app before submitting new one with the new bundle id. 
As rckoenes mentioned, if you really want to change bundle ID it is pointless to make a transfer, just delete the app from the old account and submit new app in the new account with the new bundle id.

Answer (score 2):

I just confirmed with Apple Developer Support that the bundleID can't change but the team identifier automatically transitions over to the new team in a transfer and they can edit the Team ID on request but not the bundle ID.  A senior support member is reaching out to engineering to see if there is any new information or way this might be supported but I'm not holding out hope. Crazytown.